# Huge memory usage in Nonpaged Pool

Tags: windows-7, memory, sysinternals

I have a one-year-old iMac with 8GB RAM running a bootcamped Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

The following memory analysis with Sysinternals RamMap.exe leaves some questions open:

[image]

**What could be the reason for the nearly 5 GB of memory in the Nonpaged Pool? How can I find out which driver is causing this huge memory usage?**

Comment: `!poolused 2` and `poolused 3` with WinDBG can reveal this; although you seem to have found a native approach in the Task Manager, good job!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it, you can add the column "NP Pool" to the "Processes" tab on Task Manager:

[image]

In my case, the culprit was Fling File Transfer, which has a serious memory leak. It was using more than 2 GB of the nonpaged memory pool before I restarted it. The above screenshot shows it after running for two minutes.

Bug report filed.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing that!  Everything else I'd found online involved way too many steps.  I much prefer your solution, which immediately revealed the guilty process.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution, but note that, "the Non-paged pool area seen under RAMMAP is not the same as the non-paged pool usage observed from task manager." From: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2762246

Comment: Okay, maybe the numbers don't correspond one-to-one, but it surely helped my find the process which was responsible for the high NP memory usage.

Comment: I have Nonpaged Pool of 4GB in RamMap and the largest NP Pool in Task Manger is 1MB. What now?

Comment: You have to show all users' tasks in Task Manager. See http://cdn-static.zdnet.com/i/story/60/34/000437/007_task_manager_elevated_small.jpg